# DLP - method for calculating order

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography

The DLP is defined as finding $x$, for:

$$g^x=h\pmod{p}$$

Where $p$ is prime

1) I think that to calculate the multiplicative order you take $g$ and $p$, and find $m$, where $m$ is the minimum positive integer s.t. $g^m=1\pmod{p}$.

2) Another method is that $m=order(Z_p^*)=p-1$

**Question: Which method is correct?**

I then check if $m$ can be wrote in form $q^e$, where $q$ is prime and $e \ge 1$.

I see that $q$ and $e$ can be used to calculate $x$.

I'm following the algorithm "Proposition 2.34" in Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography by Jones, Silverman et al

Comment: I liked reading Section $8.2.2$ of http://www4.ncsu.edu/~clvinzan/437/discretelog.pdf

Comment: @Moo I've read it, but I'm now more confused. There seem to be 2 different definitions of calculating order - first being smallest positive integer $m$ s.t. $g^m=1$, and second $order(Z_p)=p - 1$. What is correct?

Comment: Try reviewing Theorem 2.32 of An Introduction to Mathematical  Cryptograph, which is a great modern book.

Comment: Ok reread that. I see that in the books notation that element $g \in F_p^*$ is defined as having order $N$. And $N=p-1$. Thus order $= N = p-1 = m$. But now $g^m = g^{p-1}=1$ by FLT. Hence also $g^m=1$ ?

Comment: The multiplicative order $m$ of an element $a$ is the least integer $>0$ such that $a^m= 1$. This is your definition (1).  

For prime fields $Z_p$ (or more generally finite fields), there are always elements $g$ such that its mul. order is $p-1$, which is also the maximum (since mul. group does not include $0$). It is common (though not necessary) for DLP setups to choose $a$ as one of these $g$, if so, then its order will be $p-1$. This explains why you see case (2).  

Reason for choosing such $g$ is because $\{g^1,g^2,\dots,g^{p-1}\}$ are distinct, so you get to use the whole space.